# Asp.Net C# Nested foreach with different conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, nested

I have a table with data like this:

`ProductId   ProductName ProductPropertyOne  ProductPropertyTwo  ProductSortOrder
---------   ----------- ------------------  ------------------  ---------
1       Product 01  Propery-A       Value-01        100
1       Product 01  Propery-A       Value-02        100
1       Product 01  Propery-A       Value-03        100
1       Product 01  Propery-A       Value-04        100
1       Product 01  Propery-B       Value-01        100
1       Product 01  Propery-B       Value-02        100
2       Product 02  Propery-B       Value-01        200
2       Product 02  Propery-B       Value-02        200
2       Product 02  Propery-B       Value-03        200
2       Product 02  Propery-A       Value-01        200
3       Product 03  Propery-A       Value-01        100
3       Product 03  Propery-A       Value-02        100
3       Product 03  Propery-C       Value-01        100
3       Product 03  Propery-C       Value-02        100
3       Product 03  Propery-C       Value-03        100
3       Product 03  Propery-C       Value-04        100`

I am looping this data in my page like this:

```
<%
MyEntities db = new MyEntities();
my_ProductList = db.Product.Where(it => it.ProductPropertyOne == "Propery-A").OrderBy(it => it.ProductSortOrder).ToList();

foreach (MyData.Product Product in my_ProductList) {
%>
<a href="#"><%=Product.Name%></a>
<%}%>
```

But actually i want to have a list like this:

```
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes" data-Value-02="yes" data-Value-03="yes" data-Value-04="yes">Product 01</a>
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes">Product 02</a>
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes" data-Value-02="yes">Product 03</a>
```

So i have to let my foreach write a single line for each product (there is/would be multiple product records in table for each product with different property and values) but in the line i should write the properties as HTML data attribute.

I couldn't even come up with the logic of it.

Any idea about the logic of it?

Thanks

Comment: what are data-Value-01="yes" and data-Value-02="yes" supposed to point to in the data?

Comment: those are just some marks for the tag that will be used with css and javascript in the client side. So i should mark each line of product with the proper attributes by using the data from database

Answer (score 0):

Your example output that you provided is little confusing. May be you can explain exactly what you want to put inside `<a></a>` element and explain using column names.

From you example:

```
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes" data-Value-02="yes" data-Value-03="yes" data-Value-04="yes">Product 01</a>
```

This make sense. So you basically want to append each unique `ProductPropertyTwo` value as an attribute to `<a>` element in the form of `data-"ProductPropertyTwo"`

But then next two line don't seem to follow the exact pattern, where you have:

```
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes">Product 02</a>
<a href="#" data-Value-01="yes" data-Value-02="yes">Product 03</a>
```

These two lines don't have `data-Value-03="yes", data-Value-04="yes", etc.`

You will have to use nested for loops and then write `<a></a>` at the end of the loop. (But I see you have data sorted by productID, so you will be able to optimize the process in single loop)

But, please clarify the output example.

Based on your clarification, easiest solution I could come up in 5 minutes. Here is the "pseudo code" or not so pseudo code :) :

```
// Reason of using HashSet is so that we have only unique "ProductPropertyTwo" values for each product
Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>> myDictionary = new Dictionary<String, HashSet<String>>();
foreach(MyData.Product Product in my_ProductList)
{
    // if we are putting the new product, then create empty HashSet and then add the ProductPropertyTwo value
    if(myDictionary[Product.Name] == null){
        myDictionary.add(Product.Name, new HashSet<String>());
        myDictionary[Product.Name].add(Product.ProductPropertyTwo);
    }else{ // if product is already in Dictionary just add the "ProductPropertyTwo" value to the HashSet
        myDictionary[Product.Name].add(Product.ProductPropertyTwo);
    }
}
```

From here you can loop through dictionary again and check against your other table, then you can append attributes to `<a></a>` element

Comment: Hi; Second and Third product does not have the value-03 and value-04 attributes because there is no definition in the database for Second and Third product. I basically have to add this attributes in the tag only if the related ProductPropertyTwo value defined for that product.

Comment: Oh okay. So I assume for that you are querying or mapping those values to other table. Also, is the table always going to be sorted based on ProductId? If so, you can have it done in one pass.

Comment: Hi, Actually i have two table for and the data view i place in my question is showing combined data. First table (Product) only includes Id, Name, Sort columns. Second table (Map) includes ProductId, ProductPropertyOne, ProductPropertyTwo columns. So that i can have a single product but add as much property as we need in second table. The data you see was just a view that i used to combine data

Answer (score 0):

Based on the required final output you have provided, what you need to do is

- First, filter by the property name (you already did that).
- Then, group by the ProductName.
- For each group, format the ProductPropertyTwo values to give the desired output.
- Finally, join the formatted output from each group.

Code snippet:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string  ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductPropertyOne { get; set; }
    public string ProductPropertyTwo { get; set; }
    public int ProductSortOrder { get; set; }
}

var grouped = products.Where(p=> p.ProductPropertyOne=="Property-A").GroupBy(p => p.ProductName).Select(grp => string.Format("<a href=\"#\" {0} > {1} </a>",
    string.Join(" ", grp.Select(v => string.Format("data-{0}=\"yes\" ",v.ProductPropertyTwo))),grp.Key)).ToList();

var finalOutput= string.Join(Environment.NewLine, grouped);
```